# Finding the Most Bold Color in a Picture

Tags: image, image-processing, unity-game-engine, colors

I have an array of Colors that represents a picture. I want to find the most bold / most standout color from that frame (aka a bright pink if there is no pink in the frame or a bright yellow if there is no yellow in the frame, etc). Currently I don't know how to do this efficiently. Is there any known or efficient way of doing this efficiently for a 1280 by 720 pixel image (921,600 pixels) or any method you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, I would say you are looking for the most *saturated* colour, so I would suggest converting to `HSL` colorspace, discarding the Hue and Lightness and seeing which one has the highest saturation.

So, for a quick example using **ImageMagick** using these two images:

[image]
[image]

This is the command yo would run in Terminal:

```
convert lighthouse.png -colorspace hsl -separate -delete 0,2 saturation.png
```

And here are the results - the most saturated colours show up as white.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does Unity have a method for this? Also, when I do this on other pictures it comes up with multiple colors. Which one of those would it be?

Comment: It was just a general suggestion for an approach - I don't know the specifics of Unity or which colours seem boldest to your specific eye/tastes.

Comment: "the intensity of a colour, expressed as the degree to which it differs from white." So you could have multiple colours that are all at the same saturation. I guess it would be up to you to decide which one you want. You should supply a sample image and point out which colour you are expecting to the brightest. That way there may be a better way to get what you are expecting.

Comment: @Bonzo Yes, absolutely - thank you for sharing your insights.

Comment: For the lighthouse image it would likely be a bright pink or magenta. My current idea is to take all of the pixels in the image, sort them by R, G, and B. At this point they would look like this: (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 5), (0, 0, 6), (0, 0, 6)...(0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 10)...(170, 250, 127). From there you find the difference between each color (for the first one it would be 0 - 0 +  0 - 0 + 5 - 0 = 5) then the color would be the average of the 2 colors with the highest difference. So, if (15, 70, 15) and (75, 150, 250) have the highest difference of 375, then the "best" color would be (45, 110, 132).